# Is bitwise query like Mysql is possible?

Tags: mongodb, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

We currently have many querys who use  ' Mysql bitwise and ' 
(http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-and) like this :

```
SELECT * FROM info WHERE a & 3 AND b & 14 AND c & 6
```

Is this kind of query is possible in the last Mongodb version ?
i cannot find the answer in their manual .

regards

Comment: Look at the docs [Bitwise Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-bitwise/)

Comment: i saw but cannot find a concret example , so are you sure this can be achieve ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? Also interested.. @jess